# MSSQL 2012 import dat. file

Tags: mssql-jdbc, dat-protocol

I received an assignment to work on MSSQL 2012 and with a 'dat.' file.

I don't know how to upload the 'dat.' file to the SQL and I tried various things in order to make it work (opened it with TXT and Notepad++, tried to convert it to CSV, tried to save it as CSV and of course tried to import it to the platform) and all didn't work.

What else can I do to make it work?

opened it with TXT and Notepad++, tried to convert it to CSV, tried to save it as CSV and of course tried to import it to the platform) and all didn't work.